# How to map an a Firestore array value defined as a FieldValue

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore

I'm a bit stuck as to how to define an array value within my TypeScript interface for a Firestore document, whilst also taking advantage of FieldValue.arrayUnion(). Dependencies: TypeScript 3.7.2 and @google-cloud/firestore 2.6.0.

ie. The interface includes a 'members' key which is an array of strings:

```
import * as firestore from "@google-cloud/firestore";

interface SomeDoc {
  members: string[] | firestore.FieldValue;
}

const foo: SomeDoc = {
  members: ["s"]
};

const bar = foo.members.includes("s") ? "does include" : "does not include";
```

I can successfully update the value using the Firestore's FieldValue arrayUnion() and arrayRemove() methods, which is great. However TypeScript throws the following type error:

```
TypeScript error:
Property 'includes' does not exist on type 'string[] | FieldValue'.
  Property 'includes' does not exist on type 'FieldValue'.  TS2339
```

Anyone have any hints on how to best define this sort of value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript lets you specify any one of the types given in the union, but it does not let you read either one one of those types out without first using a [type guard to differentiate the type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types).  That section says:

> you can only access members that are guaranteed to be in all the constituents of a union type.

So, with your definition, you could satisfy TS by guarding like this:

```
const bar = (foo.members as string[]).includes("s") ? "does include" : "does not include";
```

Note that this can cause runtime errors if you guard to something that is not the actual underlying type.