# How to handle nested custom objects in Firestore data converter?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The typing of nested custom objects with Firestore seems be not possible. The typing on the [Firestore data converter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.FirestoreDataConverter) yields `WithFieldValue<T>` when attempting to convert a custom object which wraps the custom object. Expanding the tutorial [example online](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#custom_objects):

```js
class District {
  name: string;
  /* ... */
}

class City {
  name: string;
  state: string;
  districts: District[];
    constructor (name: string, state: string, districts: District[]) {
        this.name = name;
        this.state = state;
        this.districts = districts;
    }
    toString() {
        return this.name + ', ' + this.state;
    }
}

// Firestore data converter
const cityConverter = {
    toFirestore: (city) => {
        return {
            name: city.name,
            state: city.state,
            // HERE, property "map" does not exist on FieldValue
            // and firestore complains that District is a custom object
            districts: city.districts.map(/* ... */)
            };
    },
    fromFirestore: (snapshot, options) => {
        const data = snapshot.data(options);
        return new City(data.name, data.state, data.districts);
    }
};
```

This produces the error `Property 'map' does not exist on type 'FieldValue | PartialWithFieldValue<District[]> | WithFieldValue<District[]>'. Property 'map' does not exist on type 'FieldValue'.`

If we omit the mapping, then it gives the error  `Unsupported field value: a custom District object`

Is there a way to handle conversions in a type safe manner for nested objects? Existing questions mainly ignore the types and seem to utilise JavaScript only.

Comment: Have you checked this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58795466/18265570)?

Comment: Yes. The answer by Doug uses type coercion which as he points out might cause runtime errors. My question is about handling it in a type safe manner so you can write, read as well as perform FieldValue updates.

Comment: There would be a runtime error while using [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) if the type asserted is not the underlying type. `districts: (city.districts as districts[]).map(/* ... */)` this code snippet can help you to type guard conveniently without expecting to get a runtime error.

Comment: Are you still facing the issue? Did my above comment help you?

Comment: Your comment was helpful but it doesn't really answer the question because type a coercion may fail if it is an actual FieldValue such as arrayunion etc.

Comment: If I’m not wrong, ArrayUnion is not a fieldValue, [ArrayUnion](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array) 
 is a function used to add elements to an array.  And following code snippet would work in such scenarios ```await updateDoc(city, {
    regions: (city.districts as districts[]).arrayUnion("value_to_update")
});
```
Can you try it once?